# Trying to figure out if statement and GetKeyDown functions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My `if` statement runs even if the condition is not true. Variable as already been change in the first loop but due to getkeydown event it keeps looping 4 times

Just to introduce i'm making this with C# in Unity and diferent from other process it runs by frames, so each frame it will run the code again. 
So basically I'm verifying if the user as pass a situation, if not, the code will enter in the if statement and give a new value to the array index (situacao[8]) my problem is due to GetKeyDown it will run 4 times until the frame is updated (or so i read in another post).
It should be simple, since i change the value to 1 it should not enter in the if again.

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
{
    meuEstado = estado.Cela;
}
else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.G))
{
    print(situacao[8]);
    texto.text = "He look for the Window.";
    if (situacao[8] != 1)
    {
        texto.text += "\nand notice there is a bird there!";
        situacao[8] = 1;
    }
}
```

The print output is `0 - 1 - 1 - 1` but it should just give a `0`. It's not showing any console errors.

---

**PROBLEM DISCOVER:**

I had 4 textboxes associated to the same script all of them were also variable assigned.

**SOLUTION:**

Just add a script to one object and associate the other objects there

Comment: You're printing before you check if the value is 1, so it will always print the current value, 1.

Comment: Where are you running this code? Is it in the `Update` method?

Comment: Hi.. yes it's in the Update method.. the print was just for testing what i dont want is the cycle to repeat 4 times is there any way to prevent this? @RufusL

Comment: For an easiest test just place this on the Update Method and you can check that the print text will be written on the console 4 times with a single Return key press

```
   void Update()
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return))
            {
                print("space key was pressed");
            }
    }
```

Comment: @FábioRodrigues what are you talking about? Using that prints exactly one "space key was pressed" when I press return. It sounds like you have 4 copies of the same object or something not mentioned in the question

Comment: That's it! The problem was that i copy 4 textboxes and i associate them to the script 4 times :) To solve just add a script to just one object and associate the objects just there. Thank you @Ruzihm

Answer (score 3):

You're printing before you check if the value is 1, so it will always print the current value of `situacao[8]`, which is 0 the first time, then 1 for every time after that.

If you only want it to print when `situacao[8]` is not 1, consider moving it inside the if statement like so:

```
else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.G))
{
    texto.text = "He look for the Window.";
    if (situacao[8] != 1)
    {
        print(situacao[8]);
        texto.text += "\nand notice there is a bird there!";
        situacao[8] = 1;
    }
}
```

Including this script on exactly one gameobject instead of 4 will result in only "0" being printed for the first press, and for no further presses.

Comment: The print is just for testing :) I was using it to check why the cycle was looping and still i dont understand how to prevent it to cycle 4 times. The idea is when i press G it will write that 1st text and then check the variable "situacao", if 0 it add the 2nd text, if "1" it ignores it. The problem is since the cycle passes 4 times - in the 1st it will write the 1st and 2nd text. In the remaining cycle it will just overwrite the 1st text, because situacao will be like 0 - 1 - 1 - 1